# How do I pass field value as argument to next view Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I cannot find a way in the Django documentation to pass a value between different function views. I would like to create an object in my `create_player_view`, capture that new object pk and pass it to `scoring_view`. Doing this through the form action field has been unsuccessful as no data is passing between the views. What is a better way to do this?

I want a simple behavior that takes the Match ID created in `create_player_view` and passes it for update/use to `scoring_view`.

**models**

```py
class Players(models.Model):
    matchID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    player1Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    player2Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.matchID}: {self.player1Name} vs {self.player2Name}'

class Scores(models.Model):
    matchID = models.OneToOneField(Players, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match')
    p1_set_1_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p1_set_2_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p1_set_3_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p1_set_4_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    p2_set_1_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p2_set_2_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p2_set_3_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p2_set_4_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.matchID}: '
```

**views**

```
def create_player_view(request):
    """
    allows users to name two 
    players competing vs one another
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tennis:m_score') #is it possible to pass this view created instance?
        else:
            message = "Form could not be completed"

        return render(request, "create_player.html", {"message":message})

    else:
        form  = PlayerForm()
    return render(request, "create_player.html", 
            {'form': form})
    

def scoring_view(request):
    """
    View allows user to select the participating 2 players
    and record their scores per set.
    """
   
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        form = ScoresForm(request.POST )#, instance=player_instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tennis:m_results')
   
    else:
        form = ScoresForm()
        
    return render(request, "now_playing.html", {'form':form})     #todo add filtering
```

**forms.py**

```
class PlayerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Players

        exclude = ('matchID',)
        labels = {
            'playerName':('Player 1 Name', 'Player 2 Name'),
        }


class ScoresForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scores

        fields = "__all__"
```

###urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from tennis import views



app_name="tennis"

urlpatterns = [
    path('players/', views.create_player_view, name="c_pl"),
    path('scoring/<new_player>/', views.scoring_view, name="m_score"),
    path('summary/', views.match_summary_view, name="m_results"),
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you are calling scoring_view from? Is 'tennis:m_score' the name of the url for scoring_view? Adding your urls.py would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your views:

```py
def create_player_view(request):
    """"
    allows users to name two 
    players competing vs one another
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            new_player = = form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tennis:m_score', new_player=new_player)  # If you want to pass the pk instead of the object itself write: new_player=new_player.pk
        else:
            message = "Form could not be completed"

        return render(request, "create_player.html", {"message":message})

    else:
        form  = PlayerForm()
    return render(request, "create_player.html", 
            {'form': form})
    


def scoring_view(request, new_player):
    """"
    View allows user to select the participating 2 players
    and record their scores per set.
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        # You can use the value of new_player as your needs
        data = request.POST
        data['matchID'] = new_player
        form = ScoresForm(data)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tennis:m_results')
   
    else:
        form = ScoresForm()
        
    return render(request, "now_playing.html", {'form':form})     #todo add filtering
```

Comment: after using your suggestion the code is progressing but the new error is ```NOT NULL constraint failed: tennis_scores.matchID_id```

Comment: @ChillieCode Did you write `redirect('tennis:m_score', new_player=new_player)` or `redirect('tennis:m_score', new_player=new_player.pk)` in `create_player_view`? Try to write: `redirect('tennis:m_score', new_player=new_player)` without `pk`

Comment: I have used the suggestion and that's where I am seeing the error.

Comment: ```data 
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 's76GqdCF0ylHjtCT4fk9A6RiTlaheYrhzmi7aRsmHW7pQA1Ih9cKl9GK0F36CW7F',
 'matchID': 74,
 'p1_set_1_score': '0',
 'p1_set_2_score': '0',
 'p1_set_3_score': '0',
 'p1_set_4_4core': '0',
 'p2_set_1_score': '0',
 'p2_set_2_score': '0',
 'p2_set_3_score': '0',
 'p2_set_4_4core': '0'}
form 
<ScoresForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(p1_set_1_score;p1_set_2_score;p1_set_3_score;p1_set_4_4core;p2_set_1_score;p2_set_2_score;p2_set_3_score;p2_set_4_4core)>
new_player 
'74'```

Comment: @ChillieCode Even if it worked with this solution, you would have to do a total redesign of the views. Right now, you only update the score when you start a new game and this has no sense (otherwise you could just use one model for all). You'd have to write one view that creates a new game and a new score instance (in the same place so you don't have to pass parameters between views) and another to update only the score while the players are playing

Comment: @ChillieCode Do you store already finished games or do you live update the score?

Comment: @ChillieCode If the game is not live you could have only one view that creates a new score and players instance, otherwise you first need to create a players and scores instance with a view and then update the scores instance with another view. Right now it does not work well in any case

Comment: @ RedWheelbarrow Thanks, It sounds like I need a view that initiates players and their scores and then an updateview for the instantiated score instance correct?

Comment: @ChillieCode Yes I think it is the best solution